# c++ how to make a function (subroutine) argument either a vector of doubles or a vector of ints

Tags: c++, vector, arguments, 2d-vector

Hey I was just wondering is it possible in c++ to have a function in my program that as an input takes a vector or a vector. Here's an example what I want:

```
void PrintValues(const std::string& title, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& v)
{
    std::cout << title << std::endl;
    for(size_t line = 0; line < v.size(); ++line)
    {
        for(size_t val = 0; val < v[line].size(); ++val)
        {
            std::cout << v[line][val] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I have two 2d vectors I want to print in this program and I want to use a call to this function to print both one is full with doubles and the other ints. Is this possible or will my ints be auto converted to doubles??

Thanks

Comment: You could [`#include <prettyprint.hpp>`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4850473/596781) and say `std::cout << v` for *any* vector :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your function a template

```
template <typename T>
void PrintValues(const std::string& title, std::vector<std::vector<T> >& v)
{
    std::cout << title << std::endl;
    for(size_t line = 0; line < v.size(); ++line)
    {
        for(size_t val = 0; val < v[line].size(); ++val)
        {
            std::cout << v[line][val] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And the use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > x;
std::vector<std::vector<double> > y;
PrintValues("Int",x);
PrintValues("Doubles",y);
```

Comment: This part: `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` may cause an error in C++98. It should be: `std::vector<std::vector<T> >`. ;)